# Why do not we use 's for "government departments"?

Tags: attributive-nouns

Why do not we use **'s** for **"government departments"**? For example: **Government departments** are either ministerial departments or non-ministerial departments and we do not say **Government's departments** are either... .

ans also is there a clear solution for the correct usage of 's?

Comment: Clarify it further. Government departments are either ministerial or non-ministerial departments - is okay! Where 's is confusing you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apostrophe 's' ('s) can be dropped when the noun is attributive noun and acts more like an adjective than a possessor.

> [Attributive noun](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/attributive+noun) - *a noun used like an adjective and modifies another noun.*

In addition to Government Departments, this includes examples of - government policy, administration policy, portrait painter etc.

Not only for Government, there are many such examples. One of them is discussed [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16164/when-do-we-use-s-in-a-phrase/16170#comment29397_16170).